# Performance impact of rendering multiple child components with and without useCallback in a parent component

Tags: reactjs, optimization

I have a parent component  that renders several child components, and I'm curious about the performance implications of using useCallback in the code.

Here's the code snippet:

```
const renderContent = useCallback(() => {
  return (
    <FolderItemScreen
      // Props
    />
  );
}, [/* Dependencies */]);
```

return renderContent();
In the  component, there are numerous child components, each receiving multiple props. These child components can have complex logic and rendering requirements.

My question is twofold:

What are the potential performance differences between using useCallback to memoize the renderContent function and simply returning the JSX directly without useCallback?

like this:

```
return <FolderItemScreen ...props >
```

Considering the presence of multiple child components and the potential complexity of their logic, are there any performance optimizations or best practices I should consider for rendering and passing props to the child components?

I want to ensure optimal performance as the application grows. Any insights, recommendations, or examples of best practices would be greatly appreciated.

(and if there is no difference, then If I use the useCallback() , then do you guys foresee any problems with it )

Thank you in advance for your help!